# SMTPHandler sending email via Microsoft 365

Tags: python-3.6

I have this piece of code that successfully sends emails using our current on premises mail server.
Python 3.6, Redhat Linux.

I would like to convert this code to connect to our new Microsoft Cloud Mail server.

```
import logging.handlers

# mail server = ourcompanynamehere.mail.protection.outlook.com
# old mail server = mail.ourcompanynamehere.com.au
smtp_handler = logging.handlers.SMTPHandler(mailhost=("mail.ourcompanynamehere.com.au", 25),
                                            fromaddr="coolcat@ourcompanynamehere.com.au",
                                            toaddrs="coolcat@ourcompanynamehere.com.au",
                                            subject=u"Email error test!")


logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(smtp_handler)


def foo():
    raise Exception("Foo Bar")

try:
    foo()
except Exception as e:
    logger.exception('Unhandled Exception')
```

I have been told the following from our support team:

> The Office 365 relay has been setup for direct send. Please configure any applications, printers or services to use the following settings for email relays. Before we can power off the exchange server all services must be updated. This relay will only work for the on-premises environment coming from the external IP of: xx.xx.xx.xx.
>
> Device or application setting Value
> Server/smart host ourcompanynamehere.mail.protection.outlook.com
> Port  Port 25
> TLS/StartTLS  Enabled
> Email address Any email address in one of your Microsoft 365 or Office 365 verified domains. This email address does not need a mailbox.

I receive an error when trying to simply replace the server names, using the same port:

[Linux Console error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4faGi.png)

I've searched high and low through Python, StackOverflow and Microsoft without any success.

I don't know how to configure the StartTLS (I think that is the problem) to connect to our new server.

I have tried simply changing the "secure" option in the SMPTHandler to be an empty tuple, and I have tried changing username and passwords with credentials etc. From what I could find online, the empty tuple should enable the starttls for the handler. But when it comes down to it, I don't really know what Iam looking for or talking about with these security parameters. I also extended the timeout measurement to 10 and 20 seconds with no luck.

I was "hoping" that it had been configured to simply replace the server name. However, the introduction of TLS encryption appears to have complicated things.

I appreciate any help or guidance you can give me.

Comment: Sorry about the picture for the error - the system said the error looked like spam and I couldn't upload it as part of the question. Also it isn't obvious in my text  but the old and new mail servers at the top of the code are the ones I used to test with.

Comment: It appears that there was a forewall rule in place preventing traffic flowing outside of our network on that port. The code appeared to work as intended after this was changed.